# PhpStorm live template current path

Tags: phpstorm, live-templates

I want to get the current path in live templates.

Is it possible to get the current path in live templates in the PhpStorm IDE?

Answer (score 2):

There are no predefined live template macros for this. Please vote for [IDEA-55066](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-55066) and [IDEA-204994](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-204994) to be notified on any progress with these features

You can try the following expression:

```
groovyScript("com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.FileDocumentManager.getInstance().getFile(_editor.document).getParent().getName()")
```